# python, matplotlib: specgram data array values does not match specgram plot

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, spectrogram

I am using matplotlib.pyplot.specgram and matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh to make spectrogram plots of a seismic signal.

*Background information -The reason for using pcolormesh is that I need to do arithmitic on the spectragram data array and then replot the resulting spectrogram (for a three-component seismogram - east, north and vertical - I need to work out the horizontal spectral magnitude and divide the vertical spectra by the horizontal spectra).  It is easier to do this using the spectrogram array data than on individual amplitude spectra*

I have found that the plots of the spectrograms after doing my arithmetic have unexpected values.  Upon further investigation it turns out that the spectrogram plot made using the pyplot.specgram method has different values compared to the spectrogram plot made using pyplot.pcolormesh and the returned data array from the pyplot.specgram method.  Both plots/arrays should contain the same values, I cannot work out why they do not.

Example:
The plot of

```
plt.subplot(513)
PxN, freqsN, binsN, imN = plt.specgram(trN.data, NFFT = 20000, noverlap = 0, Fs = trN.stats.sampling_rate, detrend = 'mean', mode = 'magnitude')
plt.title('North')
plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.clim(0, 150)
plt.colorbar()
#np.savetxt('PxN.txt', PxN)
```

looks different to the plot of

```
plt.subplot(514)
plt.pcolormesh(binsZ, freqsZ, PxN)
plt.clim(0,150)
plt.colorbar()
```

even though the "PxN" data array (that is, the spectrogram data values for each segment) is generated by the first method and re-used in the second.

Is anyone aware why this is happening?

P.S. I realise that my value for NFFT is not a square number, but it's not important at this stage of my coding.

P.P.S.  I am not aware of what the "imN" array (fourth returned variable from pyplot.specgram) is and what it is used for....

Comment: how are they different? Can you show examples? can you provide a sample of `trN` that would allow others to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First off, let's show an example of what you're describing so that other folks

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(1)

# Brownian noise sequence
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10000).cumsum()

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(8, 10))

values, ybins, xbins, im = ax1.specgram(x, cmap='gist_earth')
ax1.set(title='Specgram')
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax1)

mesh = ax2.pcolormesh(xbins, ybins, values, cmap='gist_earth')
ax2.axis('tight')
ax2.set(title='Raw Plot of Returned Values')
fig.colorbar(mesh, ax=ax2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

### Magnitude Differences

You'll immediately notice the difference in magnitude of the plotted values.

By default, `plt.specgram` doesn't plot the "raw" values it returns. Instead, it scales them to decibels (in other words, it plots the `10 * log10` of the amplitudes).  If you'd like it not to scale things, you'll need to specify `scale="linear"`.  However, for looking at frequency composition, a log scale is going to make the most sense.

With that in mind, let's mimic what `specgram` does:

```
plotted = 10 * np.log10(values)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
mesh = ax.pcolormesh(xbins, ybins, plotted, cmap='gist_earth')

ax.axis('tight')
ax.set(title='Plot of $10 * log_{10}(values)$')
fig.colorbar(mesh)

plt.show()
```

[image]

### Using a Log Color Scale Instead

Alternatively, we could use a log norm on the image and get a similar result, but communicate that the color values are on a log scale more clearly:

```
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
mesh = ax.pcolormesh(xbins, ybins, values, cmap='gist_earth', norm=LogNorm())

ax.axis('tight')
ax.set(title='Log Normalized Plot of Values')
fig.colorbar(mesh)

plt.show()
```

[image]

### `imshow` vs `pcolormesh`

Finally, note that the examples we've shown have had no interpolation applied, while the original `specgram` plot did.  `specgram` uses `imshow`, while we've been plotting with `pcolormesh`.  In this case (regular grid spacing) we can use either.

Both `imshow` and `pcolormesh` are very good options, in this case.  However,`imshow` will have significantly better performance if you're working with a large array.  Therefore, you might consider using it instead, even if you don't want interpolation (e.g. `interpolation='nearest'` to turn off interpolation).

As an example:

```
extent = [xbins.min(), xbins.max(), ybins.min(), ybins.max()]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
mesh = ax.imshow(values, extent=extent, origin='lower', aspect='auto',
                 cmap='gist_earth', norm=LogNorm())

ax.axis('tight')
ax.set(title='Log Normalized Plot of Values')
fig.colorbar(mesh)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much, this explains everything and now I understand.

Comment: I feel this answer should have hundreds of upvotes it saved hours of time for me.

Comment: need to add values for Fs: specgram(x, Fs=1, cmap='gist_earth')