# scipy.signal.spectrogram compared to matplotlib.pyplot.specgram

Tags: matplotlib, scipy, signal-processing, spectrum, spectrogram

The following code generates a spectrogram using either `scipy.signal.spectrogram` or `matplotlib.pyplot.specgram`.

The color contrast of the `specgram` function is, however, rather low.
Is there a way to increase it?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate data
fs = 10e3
N = 5e4
amp = 4 * np.sqrt(2)
noise_power = 0.01 * fs / 2
time = np.arange(N) / float(fs)
mod = 800*np.cos(2*np.pi*0.2*time)
carrier = amp * np.sin(2*np.pi*time + mod)
noise = np.random.normal(scale=np.sqrt(noise_power), size=time.shape)
noise *= np.exp(-time/5)
x = carrier + noise
```

Using `matplotlib.pyplot.specgram` gives the following result:

```
Pxx, freqs, bins, im = plt.specgram(x, NFFT=1028, Fs=fs)
x1, x2, y1, y2 = plt.axis()
plt.axis((x1, x2, 0, 200))
plt.show()
```

[image: Image obtained with matplotlib.pyplot.specgram]

Using `scipy.signal.spectrogram` gives the following plot

```
f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(x, fs, nfft=1028)
plt.pcolormesh(t, f[0:20], Sxx[0:20])
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```

[image: Image obtained with scipy.signal.spectrogram]

Both functions seem to use the 'jet' colormap.

I would also be generally interested in the difference between the two functions. Although they do something similar, they are obviously not identical.

Comment: It would help tremenously if there was a picture here which would be described and commented on in the quesiton, such that people understand what is desired and undesired.

Comment: Is [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1593/improving-spectrogram-resolution-in-python) of any help to you?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, which helped me to better illustrate and specify the problem. As you can see in the images, the `matplotlib.pyplot.specgram` contains mainly warm colors (yellow) in the background, whereas the `scipy.signal.spectrogram contains rather cold colors (blue) in the background. I would like to achieve scipy's choice of colors for matplotlib's `specgram` plot.

Comment: I was going to answer but then saw the answer to this question (which is a duplicate, btw) and that person should just drop the mic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156050/python-matplotlib-specgram-data-array-values-does-not-match-specgram-plot

Answer (score 16):

`plt.specgram` not only returns `Pxx`, `f`, `t`, but also does the plotting for you automatically. When plotting, `plt.specgram` plots `10*np.log10(Pxx)` instead of `Pxx`.

However, `signal.spectrogram` only returns `Pxx`, `f`, `t`. It does not do plotting at all. That is why you used `plt.pcolormesh(t, f[0:20], Sxx[0:20])`. You may want to plot `10*np.log10(Sxx)`.

Comment: NB two additional differences between between matplotlib and scipy: (1) default window ; (2) default detred.  will post code soon

Answer (score 2):

With respect to the data generated in the question, found three main differences between Scipy's (v 1.7.3) and Matplotlib's (v 3.5.1) outputs:

1. default window : [#scipy-signal-windows-tukey](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.windows.tukey.html#scipy-signal-windows-tukey) vs [#matplotlib.mlab.window_hanning](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.window_hanning)
2. detrend : [scp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html#scipy-signal-spectrogram) "Defaults to 'constant'" ; [mpl](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.specgram.html?highlight=specgram#matplotlib-pyplot-specgram) "default: 'none' "
3. as noted in [a previous answer by @Sizhuang Liang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52771493/1204331) : mpl plots `Pxx` in dB

Matching Scipy's output to Matplotlib's, following the code provided in the question:

(merely to show one way to match the outputs, **not** claiming that matplotlib's defaults are any better than scipy's)

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate data
fs = 10e3
N = 5e4
amp = 4 * np.sqrt(2)
noise_power = 0.01 * fs / 2
time = np.arange(N) / float(fs)
mod = 800*np.cos(2*np.pi*0.2*time)
carrier = amp * np.sin(2*np.pi*time + mod)
noise = np.random.normal(scale=np.sqrt(noise_power), size=time.shape)
noise *= np.exp(-time/5)
x = carrier + noise
```

```py
# matplotlib

NFFT=1028
Pxx, freqs, bins, im = plt.specgram(x, NFFT=NFFT, Fs=fs)
plt.axis((None, None, 0, 200))
plt.show()
```

[image: plt.specgram]

```py
## matching scipy.__version__ == '1.7.3' to  matplotlib.__version__ == '3.5.1'

mpl_specgram_window = plt.mlab.window_hanning(np.ones(NFFT))
f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(x, fs, detrend=False,
                               nfft=NFFT, 
                               window=mpl_specgram_window, 
                              )

assert np.allclose(Sxx,Pxx), 'outputs aren't close')
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, 10*np.log10(Sxx))
plt.axis((None, None, 0, 200))
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```

[image: scipy.signal.spectrogram]

```py
Sxx_to_Pxx_dB = 10*np.log10(Sxx/Pxx)
print(f'Largest difference (ratio in dB) : {np.abs(Sxx_to_Pxx_dB).max():4.3G}')
```

> Largest difference (ratio in dB) : 5.11E-12